# Pandas sorting DataFrame with sort_value 'by' specific column problem

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have CSV file with data, that I read-in using `Pandas` `DataFrame` (no index_col). 
I'm trying to sort it using df.sort_value(by="ID", inplce=True) but i receive error: Inappropriate argument type.

CSV file looks like:

```
ID;NAME
1;ITEM1
3;ITEM2
2;ITEM3
```

I read-in the file using:

```
df_products = pd.read_csv(__file, sep=';', index_col=False)
print(type(df_products))
```

result:

```
<class pandas.core.frame.DataFrame>
```

I've tried:

```
df_products.sort_values(df_products.columns[0], inplace=True)
df_products.sort_values(by=["ID"],  inplace=True)
```

Both dosen't work, and end with:

```
Inappropriate argument type.
```

Comment: `df_products.sort_values(by="ID",  inplace=True)`

Comment: also tried that version dosen't work, maybe the reason is that, before sorting I'm appending thata with:

`pd_series = pd.Series(request.form)`
 `df_products = df_products.append(pd_series, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Can you post the dataframe head before sorting and the intended output?